# Prevent PyQGIS from converting EPSG code to OGC URN

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, wfs

I'm trying to access the [Sentinel Hub's WFS](https://www.sentinel-hub.com/develop/api/ogc/standard-parameters/wfs/) via PyQGIS. Here's my code:

```
base_url = 'https://services.sentinel-hub.com/ogc/wfs/<my_service_endpoint>?'
params = 'SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&TYPENAMES=DSS2&GEOMETRY=<some wkt polygon>'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(base_url + params, 'layername', 'wfs')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

The resulting layer is valid but the requests fail with code `400` because PyQGIS converts `EPSG:4326` to `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326` (OGC URN) as can be seen in the debugger window below:

[image]

The reason is, the Sentinel Hub WFS server doesn't understand OGC URNs, and expects a simple EPSG identifier e.g. `ESPG:4326`. Is there a way to prevent PyQGIS from performing this conversion?

**Stack**
QGIS version
3.22.1-Białowieża
QGIS code revision
663dcf8fb9
Qt version
5.12.8
Python version
3.8.10
GDAL/OGR version
3.0.4
PROJ version
6.3.1
EPSG Registry database version
v9.8.6 (2020-01-22)
OS version
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Similar topic: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338082/access-wfs-with-authentication-from-pyqgis

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that one. But that answer doesn't solve this specific problem.

Comment: What CRS identifiers are returned by the version 2.0.0 GetCapabilities response for the service?

Comment: srsname is optional so what if you don't supply it?  I also note that the coordinates in the geometry polygon, are not epsg::4326 coordinates, if they were they would have values of no greater than +/-180, so possibly you have some other issue

Comment: what is the default CRS for the featuretype?

Comment: Note that according to the WFS 2.0.0 standard a server must support  urns ~ `Servers that implement this International Standard shall be able to process srsName attribute values using the following format model:
urn:ogc:def:objectType:authority:version:<EPSG code> (see OGC 07-092r2)`

Comment: `geometry` isn't a WFS GetFeature KVP parameter though, so I suspect that that is your issue